# Generated CustomTableViewCell cellIdentifier extension in swift not possible?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I am using a number of custom implemented UITableViewCell subclasses.
Each contains this piece of code

```
    class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

        static var cellIdentifier : String {
            return (NSStringFromClass(CustomCell.self) as NSString).lastPathComponent.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
        }
    }
```

The design principle I am following is that the cellIdentifier for a particular cell always matches the cell class'es name and the associated xib file also has the same name.

> CellClassName == CellXibName == CellIdentifier.

I am trying to avoid having string constants defined only-god-knows where for  the TableView delegate to pick up when it needs the correct cell from the queue.
When I register the cells, I want instead to be able to query the Class for a static public property representing the cell identifier instead.
The code above is giving me that.
However it is obviously a duplication as I need to write it in each `CustomCell` class.

Can you please help me to make this an extension of `UITableViewCell`?
I can't specifically figure out how to replace

```
NSStringFromClass(CustomCell.self)
```

with something like this

```
NSStringFromClass(Something here, that will return the real instance's name 
                  as String, even if this code is in the extension :-/ )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**More concise solution:**

Create a new file named something like "UITableViewCellExtension.swift" with the following code:

```
import UIKit

extension UITableViewCell {

   static var cellIdentifier : String {
       return (NSStringFromClass(self) as NSString).lastPathComponent.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
   }
}
```

So this only replaces the code from your question:

```
NSStringFromClass(CustomCell.self)
```

with:

```
NSStringFromClass(self)
```

---

**other solution:**

iOS9+ solution

```
protocol Reusable {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension Reusable {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return String(mirror.subjectType).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".Type", withString: "")
    }
}

extension UITableViewCell : Reusable {
}
```

inspired by http://codica.pl/2015/08/11/protocol-extensions-and-reuseidentifier-in-uitableview/

Hope this helps.